# CSS Transition Not Firing

Tags: jquery, css, transition, css-transitions

I'm creating a DOM element (a div), adding it to the DOM, then changing its width all in one quick hit in javascript. This in theory should trigger a CSS3 transition, but the result is straight from A to B, without the transition in between.

If I make the width change through a separate test click event everything works as expected.

Here's my JS and CSS:

JS (jQuery):

```
var div = $('<div />').addClass('trans').css('width', '20px');
$('#container').append(div);
div.css('width', '200px');
```

CSS (just mozilla for the minute):

```
.trans {
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-duration: 5s;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Am I messing up here, or is the "all in one quick hit" not the way things should be done?

All help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused - do you want to animate the height or the width? or both? Also, is using jquery's .animate() method out of the question? Because if it's not, that's the way I'd recommend to do it. Let me know, and I'll write you up a simple way to do it with jQuery (or fix the CSS).

Comment: @onetrickpony – It's very unclear what additional information you're looking for with this bounty.  Could you please elaborate in a comment?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's a better way than using timeouts to make the browser update those values @Josh

Comment: @onetrickpony - Other than the answer that was accepted?  Because that's _probably_ the best way.  I guess what I'm confused about is the scenario where you wouldn't know which property was transitioned.

Comment: It's for when you have the transitions defined in the CSS file, and don't want to tell the js about them, which should only worry about appending the html and changing the class

Comment: @onetrickpony - Ah, gotcha.  Okay, what you need is a reflow, then.  I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A cleaner approach that does not rely on setTimeout, is to read the css property in question before setting it:

```
var div = $('<div />').addClass('trans');
$('#container').append(div);
div.css('width');//add this line
div.css('width', '200px');
```

Working here:

```js
var div = $('<div class="trans" />');
$('#container').append(div);

var div = $('<div />').addClass('trans');
    $('#container').append(div);
    div.css('width');//add this line
    div.css('width', '200px');
```

```css
.trans {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cyan;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
        -ie-transition: all 5s ease;
         -o-transition: all 5s ease;
            transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

As explained in the comments below by Lucero, doing it this way is necessary to force the browser to calculate an actual value rather than "auto", "inherit" or similar. Without an actual value, the browser will not know the new value to be a change from the previous.

Comment: +1 - Depending on the existing values (such as "none"), the browser needs to first process the new layout to recognize the change that triggers the transition (e.g. numeric to numeric). Reading a CSS property forces the layout to be computed.

Comment: Saved me some time of research, exactly what I needed. Such a fool requirement...

Comment: This is a better and cleaner solution than using setTimeout.

Answer (score 21):

here are two ways to do this.

**1 - CSS transitions**

by using `setTimeout` the `addClass` method will run after instead of along with the preceding script so that the `transition` event will fire

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/FYPpt/1/)

jQuery:

```
var div = $('<div class="trans" />');
$('#container').append(div);
// set the class change to run 1ms after adding the div
setTimeout(function() {div.addClass('wide')}, 1);
```

CSS:

```
.trans {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cyan;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
        -ie-transition: all 5s ease;
         -o-transition: all 5s ease;
            transition: all 5s ease;
}
.wide {
    width: 200px;
}
```

**2 - jQuery's `.animate()` function**

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/FYPpt/)

jQuery:

```
var div = $('<div class="trans" />');
$('#container').append(div);
div.animate({'width': '200px'}, 5000); // 5 sec animation
```

CSS:

```
.trans {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try calling jQuery's `.offset()` method.

When the browser gets the offset, it triggers a reflow/repaint/layout event which allows the transitions to work.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FYPpt/199/

Also see -- http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html

Comment: this is just the same as when using `div.width();` like in the accepted answer

Comment: This is cleaner because it isn't dependent on the CSS transition value, which I assume is the reason width is suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is especially useful if you change a large number of properties or don't want to hard-code the CSS properties in your JS code.

Answer (score 4):

**In response to the bounty:**

If you don't have the luxury of knowing which property is being transitioned or simply don't think it's good practice to force a `setTimeout` to get an animation to fire, you can force a reflow in another way.

The reason that `setTimeout` works in the first place is due to the fact that you're causing a full document reflow in the meantime, even if the duration is set to `0`.  That's not the only way to cause a reflow.

---

## [Link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYPpt/204/)

**JavaScript**

```
for (x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10), i=0;i<x;i++){
    $('<div />').appendTo($('#container')).addClass('trans');
}

var divs = $('#container div');
var x = divs.eq(Math.ceil(Math.random() * divs.length));
x[0].offsetHeight;
x.addClass('wide');
```

With this JavaScript we're randomly adding between 1 and 10 `div` elements, and then selecting one of those at random and adding the `wide` class.

You'll notice an odd line of JavaScript in there, namely `x[0].offsetHeight`.  This is the lynchpin to the whole operation.  Calling `offsetHeight` triggers the document to reflow without using a setTimeout or querying the CSS value.

What a reflow is in relation to the DOM:

> A reflow computes the layout of the page.  A reflow on an element
>   recomputes the dimensions and position of the element, and it also
>   triggers further reflows on that element’s children, ancestors and
>   elements that appear after it in the DOM.  Then it calls a final
>   repaint.  Reflowing is very expensive, but unfortunately it can be
>   triggered easily.

So please be judicious in how you use these functions.  Not too much of a concern with most modern browsers (as jQuery is notorious for firing several reflows), but still something to consider before adding something like this solution all over your website.

---

**Important note:** This is *no more or less efficient than a* `setTimeout` *call*.  This isn't a magic bullet solution, and it's doing the same thing under the hood.

---

Here's the corresponding CSS, for reference:

```
.trans {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cyan;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
         -o-transition: all 5s ease;
            transition: all 5s ease;
}

.trans.wide {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Actually calling `width()` seems to do the job, even if other props are transitioned. I feel silly now for not testing it :)

Answer (score 2):

as @onetrickpony was asking, what if all rules are in the CSS file and should not be added in the JS-function.

Based on the answer from Torin Finnemann, just with a slight change:

Add an extra class where rules are defined: `new-rules`

```
var div = $('<div class="trans" />');
$('#container').append(div);

var div = $('<div />').addClass('trans');
$('#container').append(div);
div.height();
div.addClass('new-rules');
```

in your CSS have the class predefined:

```
.trans.new-rules {
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

now there is no need tingling with the JS when changing the CSS. Change it in the CSS-file at `new-rules` :)

http://jsfiddle.net/FYPpt/201/

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = $('<div />');

$('#container').append(div);

div.css('width', '20px').addClass('trans', function() {
   div.css('width', '200px') 
});
```

Creates a new DIV element and adds the 'trans' class to that element in order to fire the CSS transition

Comment: What is this..? What does this do..?

Comment: Re-ordering the functions so that the div is created first, followed by addClass  with a callback to set the width after the addclasw transition -- it will definately fire that way ... not sure the exact reqs of the code but i know this will work

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add the explanation there... code only answers are not encouraged here...