# CSS transitions don't work unless I use timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a couple of classes: `hide` is `display: none`, and `transparent` is `opacity: 0`. The element `pr_container` has `-webkit-transition: opacity 1s`. The following JQuery-based code makes an element appear in an animated fasion:

```
pr_container.removeClass("hide");
setTimeout(function() { pr_container.removeClass("transparent"); }, 0);
```

However, when I remove `setTimeout` and instead just remove the second class, there is no animation. Why?

Edit: I'm using the latest Chrome, I haven't checked other browsers yet.

Edit: I tried putting both calls in the same `setTimeout` callback - no animation. So it's clearly about separation.

Edit: here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WfAVj/

Comment: How are you calling this code? Can you provide a jsfiddle to show what's happening?

Comment: @Lorax here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/WfAVj/

Comment: If you are using jQuery, is there a reason you want the animation to be handled by CSS transition? Using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) would probably yield better cross-browser functionality.

Comment: Involving `display` in transition will end up with no transition at all, AFAIK. By using `setTimeout(func,0)`, you separated the transition with `display:none`, so it works.

Comment: @RubenInfante, that's not the point, I want to know why the browser behaves the way it does.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko That is fine, I just wanted to throw that out there given that you had only tested in Chrome. In any case, this situation would appear to have been asked/answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3332179/2034234

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko [Cleaner solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069167/css-transition-not-firing#answer-19907889) is way better than using setTimeout, it reads propety first before changing again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a transition if you are changing `display` property at the same time. So in order to make it work you have to hide your element some other way. For example:

```
.hide {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* overflow: hidden; padding: 0; border: none; */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/WfAVj/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I have `position: fixed` elements inside, and I do :(

Comment: Another question: how does the browser know if I'm gonna add/remove another class right now? Or if I put `removeclass("hide")` last, is it going to perform the animation just fine?

Comment: But if you `removeClass('hide')` the last in this case you will not see changes.

Comment: You can also try `visibility: hidden;`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reasonable "[curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)" to transit from one `display` status to another, so in current implementation of browsers, any transition that somehow involves `display` will end up with no transition at all.

With this code:

```
pr_container.removeClass("hide");
pr_container.removeClass("transparent");
```

You can imagine the two statements execute in a single "blocking" queue, so browsers practically renders the element from `class="hide transparent"` to `class=""`, and as stated above, the `hide` class practically invalidates any existing transition.

By using

```
pr_container.removeClass("hide");
setTimeout(function() { pr_container.removeClass("transparent"); }, 0);
```

You told browsers to remove the "transparent" class "as soon as possible, but no in the same queue", so browser first removes "hide", and then moves on. The removal of "transparent" happens when the browser think it has resource to spare, thus the transition does not get invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

only the "transperent" class produce animation .. "hide" is instant. So start the animation and if needed "hide" after 1 second:

```
 test.addClass("transparent");
 //hide after 1 sec, when the animation is done
 setTimeout(function() {test.addClass("hide"); }, 1000);  //1000ms = 1sec
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WfAVj/4/

Comment: That wasn't the part I was worrying about :)

Answer (score 0):

By using suggestions in the linked question, I made a version that I'm satisfied with:

```
.test {
    -webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.transparent {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKgjS/

Edit: now the two classes can even be combined to one!

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Using `visibility:hidden` is not the same as `display:none`: http://jsfiddle.net/xKgjS/1/ But that's fine if it fits your need.