# How to add multiple css proerty in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery to add css to a div, it works well when I add just one css property

here is the code;

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
        jQuery('#myheader2').css('background-color', '#fff');
    } else {
       jQuery('#myheader2').css('background-color', '#fff');
    }
});
```

However if add more than one css property, it stops working;

here is the code;

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
        jQuery('#myheader2').css({'background-color': '#fff','transition': 'background-color 3s';});
    } else {
       jQuery('#myheader2').css('background-color', '#0b0b22');
    }
});
```

I looking to add transition to slow the speeed of background color change.

Comment: add a class and have css for that class be the required styling?

Comment: @depperm [easy and correct way? No!](https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Drake-Hotline-Bling.jpg)

Comment: I believe that `transition` needs to be a permanent CSS property of `#myheader2` so that it knows the `from` and `to` states to transition between.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Transition Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069167/css-transition-not-firing)